# Error on _SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies not symbol found

Tags: macos, gcc, osx-snow-leopard, cfnetwork

compiling my project i got an error: SYmbol not found to _SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies 
any ideas?

Comment: Have you linked the System Configuration framework?

Answer (score 6):

Bit late but I faced the same issue.
For me adding this to the compiler command helped.

```
-framework Foundation -framework SystemConfiguration
```

Comment: Adding -framework SystemConfiguration resolved this for me, too.  But in my case the first -framework is CoreFoundation, rather than Foundation.